# How do I count the number of children belonging to a selected list of parents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list- grandparent.parents.where(:alive => true) and I need to count the children belonging to these parents (whom belong to this particular grandparent).

Eventually, I'm looking to sum the alive parents count & that of their children- but hopefully I should be fine, once I've had a hand with this first bit...

Clearly grandparent.parents.where(:alive => true).children.count doesn't work, but hopefully you get what I'm aiming at...

Thanks in advance for any help, really much appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) except for `grandparent.parents.where(:alive => true).children.count`?

Comment: It would be nice if you included your model structures.

Comment: structures? apologies, I'm so new I'm not even sure I know what you're asking for! I'm confident the relationships between models are set up as you would expect for grandparents, parents, children etc...

Comment: I guess what @nicooga meant, is that you should post your models code, or at least a description of how "models are set up".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the relationship between parents and a child is the simple `has_one` and `belongs_to` --therefore assuming that you have a `parent_id` attribute for the `Children` model. I'm also assuming that only one parent is listed in the `Parents` model for each child...lots of assumptions, so let us know your model structures.

If the above assumptions are true, try this for the total number of children for all those parents:

```
array = []
grandparent.parents.where(:alive => true).each do |parent|
     c = Children.find_all_by_parent_id(parent.id).count
     array << c
end

array.sum
```

Or this for the number of children for each parent:

```
    grandparent.parents.where(:alive => true).each do |parent|
        Children.find_all_by_parent_id(parent.id).count
    end
```